# Using em for responsive styles on things other than type

Tags: css, responsive-design, less, font-size

Sometimes I wish I could just change a single variable in a media query and

HTML:

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

**LESS (does not work):**

```css
@base: 1000px;

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  @base: 600px;
}

.child1 {
  // 500px normally, 300px on small screens
  height: 0.5 * @base;
}
.child2 {
  // 250px normally, 150px on small screens
  height: 0.25 * @base; 
  }
```

That of course doesn't work because at compilation time, `@base` is set and applied to all classes. However, I came across this dirty workaround:

**LESS:**

```css
#wrap 
    {
    font-size: 1000px;
    @media all and (max-width: 768px) {
      font-size: 600px;
    }
    .child1 {
      // 500px normally, 300px on small screens
      height: 0.5em;
    }
    .child2 {
      // 250px normally, 150px on small screens
      height: 0.25em; 
      }
    }
```

Assuming I don't actually have any text in my elements (or text only occurs in leaf nodes and sets their font-size explicitly), are there any serious downsides of using this approach?

Comment: I am not sure if I actually understood your question, but why do you declare you media query before the "normal" CSS? I would recommend you to go mobile first, meaning you start with the design for a small screen and then go up.

Comment: "mobile-first" doesn't actually change the approach at all. The question is about whether it is safe to use `em` units to set the size of boxes and media queries to change the font-size for an entire sub-tree of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot attest for certain, but the proposed `em` method just seems too hacky for my taste (and it does not make the heights of the elements easily determined by the coder). I would recommend using the media queries as they are intended to be used, and just build a mixin to get the values, like so:

**LESS**

```
@base: 1000px;
@smallBase: 600px;

.childHeights(@base) {
  // 500px normally, 300px on small screens
  .child1 {
  height: 0.5 * @base;
  }
  // 250px normally, 150px on small screens
  .child2 {
    height: 0.25 * @base;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .childHeights(@smallBase);
}

.childHeights(@base);
```

**CSS Output**

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
  .child1 {
    height: 300px;
  }
  .child2 {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
.child1 {
  height: 500px;
}
.child2 {
  height: 250px;
}
```